# How to set encoding in Apache HTTP Components?

Tags: java, apache-httpcomponents

How do I set the character encoding in Apache HTTP Components?

I do something like this:

```
    Form form = Form.form();
    form = form.add("somekey", "somevalue");
    Request request = Request.Post("http://somehost/some-form")
                             .request.bodyForm(form.build());
```

"somekey" and "somevalue" are unicode strings because all java string are unicode. http components converts them to latin-1 when I tested. I want it to convert to something else (e.g., utf-8).

Comment: I don't understand your question, please clarify with some code if possible.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: submit a String to the apache http compoonents library. String in Java means unicode. It gets converted to latin-1 for me. I want to change what it gets converted to, e.g utf-8

Comment: You won't get any result in Google nor here. Update your question based in your comment (at least is easier to understand that the actual question).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Going by what you've shown in your example, you seem to be using the fluent API.

Looking into the [javadocs](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/fluent-hc/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/fluent/class-use/Request.html) there is a version of `request.bodyForm()` that accepts a charset:

```
    import org.apache.http.Consts;
    ...
    request = request.bodyForm(form.build(), Consts.UTF_8);
```

According to the [source](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/httpcomponents-httpclient/httpcomponents-httpclient-4.2.1/org/apache/http/client/fluent/Request.java.html#line.269), the charset defaults to `Consts.ISO_8859_1` (a.k.a. Latin-1).

### Alternatives

1. If that doesn't work, consider:

   ```
   import org.apache.http.Consts;
   ...
   request.elementCharset(Consts.UTF_8);
   ```
2. As a last resort, it should be possible to set the content charset. Looking at the [source for `elementCharset()`](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/httpcomponents-httpclient/httpcomponents-httpclient-4.2.1/org/apache/http/client/fluent/Request.java.html#line.225), you could try the following:

   ```
   import org.apache.http.Consts;
   import org.apache.http.params.CoreProtocolPNames;
   ...
   request.config(CoreProtocolPNames.HTTP_CONTENT_CHARSET, Consts.UTF_8);
   ```

Comment: There is typo request = request.bodyForm(form.build(), Consts.UTF_8);